# How to configure caffeine cache in camel

Tags: caching, apache-camel, caffeine-cache

I am adding a cache (caffeine) to rest api call in camel code.

Please consider the code below:

```
@Component
public class TenantIdService extends ServiceBaseRouteBuilder {

    @Value("${platform.endpointsOrchestrated.tenantId}")
    private String msEndpoint;
    @Value("${spring.cache.caffeine.maximumSize}")
    private String maximumSize;
    @Value("${spring.cache.caffeine.expireAfterWriteTime}")
    private String expireAfterWriteTime;
    @Value("${spring.cache.caffeine.cacheName}")
    private String cacheName;
    private StmKafkaDTO stmKafkaDTORequest;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        super.configure();
        

        from(direct(CALL_CACHE))
                .toF("caffeine-cache://%s?evictionType=TIME_BASED&expireAfterWriteTime=%s&maximumSize=%s",
                        cacheName,
                        expireAfterWriteTime,
                        maximumSize);

        // cached call
        from(direct(ADD_TENANT_ID))
                .unmarshal().json(StmKafkaDTO.class)
                .process(exchange -> {
                    stmKafkaDTORequest = exchange.getIn().getBody(StmKafkaDTO.class);
                    exchange.setProperty(STM_EVENT_EXCHANGE_PROPERTY, stmKafkaDTORequest.getPayload());
                })

                // Check if result is in cache
                .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant("get"))
                .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.KEY, constant("TranslateEvent"))
                .to(direct(CALL_CACHE).getUri())
                //TODO: test log
                .log("Has Result ${header.CamelCaffeineActionHasResult} ActionSucceeded ${header.CamelCaffeineActionSucceeded}")
                .log("Cache body: ${body}")
                .choice()
                    .when(header(CaffeineConstants.ACTION_HAS_RESULT).isEqualTo(Boolean.FALSE))
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Cache miss. Calling TranslateEvent...")
                        // Cache miss, call the endpoint
                        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
                        .toD(msEndpoint + Util.BRIDGE_ENDPOINT + Util.THROW_EXCEPTION_OFF)
                        .unmarshal().json(CoCountryMappingDTOResponse[].class)
                        .process(TenantIdMapper::mapResponse) // Map the cached response
                        .process(PublishToPlatService::publishStmEventToPlatform) // Publish the mapped response
                        .setHeader(CaffeineConstants.ACTION, constant("put")) // Cache the result
                        .to(direct(CALL_CACHE).getUri())
                    .otherwise()
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Cache hit. Response from cache: ${body}")
                        .process(TenantIdMapper::mapResponse) // Map the cached response
                        .process(PublishToPlatService::publishStmEventToPlatform) // Publish the mapped response
                .end()
                .stop();

    }
}
```

How can I set and configure the cache instead of passing the parameters every time I do a call to the cache?
I have try with caffeineCacheBuilder but seems that my custom cache is overwrited by the default one
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the component level options [1] setting them in the `application.properties` file

It would be literally something like:

```
camel.component.caffeine-cache.expire-after-access-time=100
camel.component.caffeine-cache.expire-after-write-time=100
...
```

When you're using the component, if the specific parameter is not set in the URI, then, it should be taken from here.

[1] https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/caffeine-cache-component.html#_spring_boot_auto_configuration